# Limit textbox to 10 digits with and also with allowed decimals in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on a problem and searching for it, but couldn't find one.
I have a text field where I want to allow 10 digits and decimal values, for example my allowed digits would be:

```
1.11
1234567890
```

Anything within 10 digit range (have problems in these cases below)

```
12345678.13
123456789.05
1234567890.12
```

I can already restrict textbox to 10 digits but the question is how to allow only 2  decimals after 10 digits.

My code is:

```
function CheckNumber(textBoxValue,evt){
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 37) {
  return true;
   } else if (charCode == 46 && textBoxValue.indexOf('.') != -1) {
  return false;
   } else if (charCode > 31 && charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  return false;
   }
   console.log(charCode);
   if(textBoxValue.length){
    newVal = textBoxValue.split('.');
      console.log(newVal);

    if(newVal[0].length > 9){
      if(charCode == 46){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code please. We need to see what you got so far.

Comment: added the code now.

Comment: Should the period be considered part of the ten-digit limit?

Comment: no, the period and the decimal value after should not be included in limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhmm, why not use regex for this? Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L18d0qut/3/

**EDIT:**

I changed the code accordingly. Is this fiddle working for you?

I modified the checks to meet your criteria. The key code is now this:

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){

    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.match(/^[0-9,.]*$/)) {

    if(value.indexOf(".") >= 0 || value.indexOf(",") >= 0){
        console.log("YAY, we have a float, so it is valid!");
    } else if(value.length <= 10) { 
        console.log("Valid!");
    } else {
        console.log("invalid!");
    }


    } else {
        console.log("Only numbers and . or , are allowed!");
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** This works for floating numbers with `.` and also with `,`. If you do not want this you can simply modify to your needs in the `regex` and `indexOf()` methods.

I check the length of the input AND check for the contents by regex. Is this what you're looking for?

**Just have a look in the console for the result :-)**.

Comment: the problem is when i try this: 123456789.12

Comment: Well it is totally working fine for me with this case. Is it only this value that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: not specific, but if I enter values like 123456789.05 or 12345678.12 or this 1234567890.12 etc it returns NO.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, check now if it works for you. I can't find any issue.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear with my question, but what i need is "The digits can be maximum of 10 in length but with decimals it can be greater than 10 (for e.g.1234567890 and 123456789.15 should both be valid)".

Comment: Ah okay I get it, I‘ll update the code as soon as possible, it‘s just a small change

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code & created something like this.

```
function CheckNumber(textBoxValue,evt){
 evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 37) {
    return true;
  } else if (charCode == 46 && textBoxValue.indexOf('.') != -1) {
    return false;
  } else if (charCode > 31 && charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  //console.log(charCode);
  if(textBoxValue.length){
      newVal = textBoxValue.split('.');
      /*console.log(newVal[1]);*/
        if(typeof(newVal[1])!='undefined'){
            if(newVal[1].length !=2){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(newVal[0].length > 9){
            if(charCode == 46){
                return true;
            }
            if((charCode >= 48 || charCode <=57) && newVal[0].length == 10 && textBoxValue.indexOf('.') != -1 ){
                if(newVal[1].length !=2){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }       
          return false;
        }
  }
  return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check

```
if(newVal[1].length > 2){
 // your code
}
```

Comment: I can calculate the number of decimals but my question is how to add this type of value 123456789.12 or 12345678.12 or this 1234567890.12

Comment: You mean to say that before decimal you need max 10 and then after decimal 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function IsValid(input) {
    return (/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,2})?$/).test(input);
}
```

This allows 10 digits and 2 (optional) decimals. Input must be string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..............

```
function CheckNumber(textBoxValue,evt){
    var a = textBoxValue.replace('.', '');
    if(a.length <= 10){
        console.log("valid");
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code allow you only two decimal digits and 10 number before decimal point

/^\d **{0,12}** (.\d{0,2})?$/;

you can set your textbox length by {0,12} where 0 : min length and 12 : max length

```js
 function IsValidNumber(Number) {
            var expr = /^\d{0,12}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
            return expr.test(Number);
        };
        function ValidateNumber() {
            var Number = document.getElementById("txtNumber").value;
            if (!IsValidNumber(Number)) {
                alert("Invalid number");
            }
            else {
                alert("Valid number.");
            }
        }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="txtNumber" />
    <input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate" onclick = "ValidateNumber()" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered textbox input pattern using regex?

Something like `pattern="\d{10}\.\d{2}$"`

Comment: yes, i have; but the same issue as I was not able to find/create the proper regex required. Please share if you have regex required for above case.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, since you're explicitly seeking clarification from the OP.

Comment: Added example to my answer